# Flask deploy on ec2 Amazon aws

Tags: python, flask

What is the best pratice to deploy a Python Flask website on ec2 Amazon aws? 
I saw some tutorial for uwsgi and ngnix...but I don't know if is correct to follow this path.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way would be to go through Elastic Bean Stalk. It does not use uwsgi, instead, it uses Apache with mod_wsgi. This way you can only focus on application instead of worrying about the backend. EB takes care of that for you.

You can find more info about deploying Flask application in BeanStalk :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html

https://github.com/kmrambo/Deploying-a-Flask-or-Dash-application-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk

Note: If you really want to learn, I will suggest to go ahead and do things manually. You can implement Apache + mod_wsgi and you will have a great learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

If your Flask app is simple enough, perhaps [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) would be an option for you (to deploy your Flask application to [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)). I currently host several web apps and APIs on Lambda using Zappa and find it very reliable. I still need to use EC2 for a few applications, in particular ones that use Websockets as this requires long-lived connections which don't really work that well in a serverless environment. In these cases I find using the Nginx/Gunicorn stack simple and reliable.

Comment: There's something basic I'm missing on this topic. If my Flask app works on Windows 7 using localhost:5000... why do I need to fuss with a web server when I deploy it to EC2? I thought Flask was taking care of the http routing overhead that a web server would have to handle. I'm using the flask_socketio library to handle events.

I got my app running on EC2 today and opened port 80 for HTTP protocol... but I keep getting CONNECTION REFUSED error. Is that because of the lack of a formal web server running on the instance?